# Alliance Timer Help Not Clearing

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

I have an issue where my Alliance is helping me speed up the building timer but it seems to then stay on 12/12 and not complete the building process until the timer has actually run its course. I have just recently changed alliances. Not sure if that has something to do with it or if it is a program bug.

Comment: If it *is* a bug, I'm afraid we can't help you (I don't know anything about the game though), in that case reporting the bug to the developer sounds like a good plan.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behavior.  Filling the help progress bar only indicates the number of people within your alliance that have helped you with your task.

For instance, start with 0/12.  When 6 people click help, that will update to 6/12.  And finally when all 12 people in your alliance have helped, it will show 12/12

The difference is that the help only gives 1 minute of reduction of time, so if your task is a 20 minute long task, and 12 people help, thats 12 minutes reduced from the total task duration.  20 - 12 = 8 minutes, so you'd have 8 minutes left before the task is complete.

Also, the number of helps is governed by the level of the [Stronghold](http://gow-fireage.wikia.com/wiki/Stronghold).  I believe the formula is 4+the stronghold level, so if your stronghold is level 10, you can have up to 14 helps.